# Google Maps Api V2 in Fragment with ActionBar Tab

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app with an Action Bar and 3 tabs. When I touch the second Tab I need to show a Google Maps V2 inside the fragment.

This is My MapFragment class:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container,
            false);


    setUpMapIfNeeded(v);
    return v;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View v) {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((GoogleMap) v.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title(
            "Marker"));
}
```

}

For this line of code in the setUpMapIfNeeded method :

```
mMap = ((GoogleMap) view.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I get an error: The method getMap() is undefined for the type GoogleMap

It's the first time I do that and I search for the good way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please consider reading this. This should help you achieve what you want!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

modify :

```
mMap = ((GoogleMap) view.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
mMap = ((GoogleMap) view.findViewById(R.id.map));
mMap.getMap();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I get the map.  It's not a google map its a SupportMapFragment.

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements
    BestRidesSettingsDialogListener, SnapshotReadyCallback,
    OnMapLoadedCallback {
```

...

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The Layout straight from the fragment sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Good Luck